# code for sending data from android to VB through wifi

Tags: android, vb.net, client-server, wifi

I want to create a food order system at the restaurant using the android and VB. so the waiter will use Android to transmit data to the cashier who use VB.
Is it possible to connect Android to VB?
anyone please help..

VB version i used is Visual Basic 2010. i used Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express..
Database in VB use SQLExpress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Totally. What you probably want to do is have your VB app listening on a port for data from the Android app, and the Android app would just send data to your app using that port.

This is the basis of fundamental communication using sockets.

Android has a class called Socket that will handle this on the client end, and there is the equivalent for VB, depending on which version you are using.

Some links that might be useful:

http://www.prasannatech.net/2008/07/socket-programming-tutorial.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html

http://osix.net/modules/article/?id=25

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.aspx

Comment: i try to read 4 links above but i still can't understant :'( so bad.. can anyone give some simple example please..